# Difference in physical meaning between $\vec{D}$ and $\vec{E}$

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

I understand that $\vec{D}=\varepsilon_0 \vec{E} + \vec{P}$, but, physically, what is the difference between these two vector quantities? What is their physical meaning?

Comment: You can start by checking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field and http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/jk1/Electromagnetism/node40.html

Comment: I understand all the math behind it, but I would like to discuss the physical meaning of these two quantities.